# Tcp server close stuck at TIME_WAIT, cannot open server on the same port again

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am using LwIP 1.4.1, my tcp server close is stuck at TIME_WAIT condition, hence I am unable to open server on the same port again. I have tried `SO_REUSE (#define SO_REUSEADDR 1`), but this also doesn't work, anyone have ideas?

In time wait I have check that after around 30 secs, it goes out of timeout, I don't want to wait that long.

Comment: I guess problem is in handshaking. You are trying to close the socket so server is verifying with TIME_WAIT that no more data left in pipe, But other party is continuously sending data. Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `#define SO_REUSEADDR 1`? This is not the correct way to set SO_REUSEADDR.

Comment: @Dayalrai yes the problem is in handshaking, I am seeing the proper handshaking on sniffer i.e. Server sends FIN, receives ACK, receives FIN, sends ACK. But on module its connection state is not changing, it is stuck at TIME_WAIT. On the other side, remote pc stops sending data, its connection closes and it cannot connect again.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option on the socket before calling `bind()`:

> Linux will only allow port reuse with the SO_REUSEADDR option when this
>          option was set both in the previous program that performed a bind(2) to
>          the port and in the program that wants to reuse the port.  This differs
>          from  some implementations (e.g., FreeBSD) where only the later program
>          needs to set the SO_REUSEADDR option.   Typically  this  difference  is
>          invisible,  since,  for example, a server program is designed to always
>          set this option.

The fact that you still have to wait indicates that the option was not set.

Comment: I am not on linux, any idea on how to use it in Raw TCP in LwIP ver 1.4.1 . I could only find this macro `#define SO_REUSE 1`, I've searched a forums, couldn't find.

Comment: @Ishmeet `SO_REUSE` macro must be set when compiling LwIP library. Was your LwIP library compiled with that macro on?

Comment: YES, It is inside `opt.h`, and I have recompiled the whole thing, as a proof I have debug msg inside `#if SO_REUSE` macro and it prints.

Comment: @Ishmeet well then, you may have better luck asking LwIP experts on their mailing lists: http://savannah.nongnu.org/mail/?group=lwip

Answer (score 0):

set SO_REUSEADDR socket option. One more point using SO_REUSEADDR can through an error, "address already in use". SO_REUSADDR allow  to use a port that is stuck in TIME_WAIT, but we still can not use that port to establish a connection to the last port it connected to. if the server is at 3000, and connect to client  port 4000, and then close locally, leaving that port in TIME_WAIT. we can reuse server port 4000 right away to connect to anywhere except for client port 4000